# Does Spring Data intentionally allow for unknown tokens when generating queries from method names?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In one of my Spring Data repositories I wanted to have two autogenerated methods for finding a single instance by ID, one returning the full entity (`Student`) and the other a  slimmer projection (`StudentView`). Now obviously Java won't let me have two methods that differ only in return type:

```
Optional<Student> findById(String id);
Optional<StudentView> findById(String id);
```

I could have named one of the methods to whatever else I wanted and manually provided it with the required query via a `@Query` annotation, but I wanted to make use of method-name autogeneration. Now Spring Data does allow for some flexibility in how it parses the method name, and so I could have named one of the methods as (say) `findOneById()` to distinguish it from the other, but that didn't feel right. However in the course of experimentation I discovered that I could name the second method as `findViewById()`, that is containing a token `View` that is not one of the keywords known to the method-name parser:

```
Optional<Student> findById(String id);
Optional<StudentView> findViewById(String id);
```

Does the method-name parser intentionally allow for this (I cannot find mention of it in the documentation), or am I merely exploiting an accident of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This looks bizarre, but it looks like in `Spring-Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE` you can use whatever word you want between `find` and `ById`.

`Optional<Student> findWhateverById(Long Id)` will return record of `student` table with provided `id`.

Either I'm missing something or it's indeed a bug.